# rolling Sample standard deviation in excel

Tags: excel

I am calculating in excel, a rolling 37 days sample standard deviation of a data set from FTSE100,i am a little confuse with "rolling 37 days." after calculating the mean for whole data (i.e.the closing price),I calculated the standard deviation by starting from the 38th mean and applying the excel function =STDEV(C38:C1023)/(37-1). please have I done the right thing?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. The /(37-1) part is already in the STDEV formula.
What you need is
    =STDEV(C1:C37)
in D37 (or other column). And then just drag formula to D1023.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, does it imply that the sample mean (=(AVERAGE(C37:C1023)/37-1) was wrong?   =STDEV(D37:D1023) is this the sample standard deviation?

Comment: Yes for both, why would you divide average by 36?

Comment: hmmmm very confuse, may be I ve to let u look at the data

Comment: Would be nice. You can try to post the structure, some sample data.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-stack-overflow-post

You can post the link here

Comment: I don't ve 5 reputation on stack overflow so I am not permitted to ask question on meta

Comment: The link I've given you is about how to attach.. You don't need to post there